# How does Kafka consumer handle partially committed transactions?

Tags: apache-kafka, transactions

I'm trying to understand Kafka transaction guarantees precisely. As far as I understand from [the design document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/11Jqy_GjUGtdXJK94XGsEIK7CP1SnQGdp2eF0wSw9ra8/edit?usp=sharing), Kafka uses two-phase commit protocol for transactions, so if I commit a transaction involving partitions A and B, the following actions sequence is possible:

- Coordinator send messages to both partition leaders
- the leaders write messages to their message logs
- Coordinator sends commit transaction message to the leaders
- Leader A adds `commit` marker to message log, but Leader B times out
- Coordinator marks the transaction as aborted in the transaction log
- Transactional Consumer reads data from partition A, sees the `commit` marker and delivers the message to client, which obviously violates transactional semantics

Am I missing something? Maybe consumers/brokers somehow interact with the transaction log/coordinator to double-check that transaction is not aborted?